# C segmentation error whiler generating prime numbers in an array

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, primes

I wrote this code to perform a stress test on my computer. It actually generate all prime numbers until the value defined by MAXX.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> 
#include <omp.h>
#define MAXX 2059000

int main() {

    int primes[MAXX];
    primes[0] = 3;
    int entry=1; 

    for (int test=5; test < MAXX; test+=2){

        int flag=1; //assumed prime

        for (int div=0; primes[div] < sqrt(test); div++){

            if(test % primes[div] ==0){

                flag = 0;
                break;      
            }           
        }
        if (flag==1){

        primes[entry]=test;
        entry++;
        printf("%d \n", test);
        }
    }
```

If i increase the value of MAXX i get a segmentation error. How can i solve it?

Comment: Looks like a classic stack overflow - `primes` is too large for a local variable.

Comment: Local variables (a.k.a. automatic variables) are usually stored on the stack by the compiler. The stack is a limited resource, on Linux the default stack size per process is 8MiB. If `sizeof(int) == 4` (which is the most common) then with a highe enough value for `MAXX` your array will be larger than those 8MiB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a limit to how much you can have on the stack. Instead of this

```
int primes[MAXX];
```

You could try this:

```
int *primes = malloc(MAXX * sizeof(int));
if (primes == NULL){
    printf("%Error: Out of memory.\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Now it's not allocated on the stack, but on the heap. At the end of the program, free the memory again:

```
free(primes);
```

And while you're at it, remember that `main` returns an `int`, so put this right after:

```
return 0; // 0 usually means "program execution was successful"
```